# Информацию полученную через CURL поместить в массив

Tags: php, curl

Всем привет. Я не особо разбираюсь в CURL, раньше использовал функцию file_get_contents для того, что бы получить информацию со странички и помещать её в массив. В общем такой вопрос, как получить информацию со странички через CURL и поместить её в массив для дальнейшей работы? Пытаюсь сделать что то типо этого, но получаю ошибку Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
    function curl_load($url){
        curl_setopt($ch=curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '***.ru');
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    $lines= curl_load('http://emeraldscity.combats.ru/inf.pl?short=1327641470');

        foreach($lines as $value)
        { 
                list($var, $val) = explode('=',$value); 
            $arr[$var] = $val; 
        }
$level = $arr['level'];
echo $level;
```

Comment: $lines= curl_load('http://emeraldscity.combats.ru/inf.pl?short=1327641470');
$lines = explode("\r\n",$lines);

Comment: что за язык то хоть? php?